# Have a jQuery variable update in real time?

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a map that has a draggable pin using jQuery, and I've created a simple function to get the `left` and `top` CSS properties.  The only problem is, if I drag the pin around, the variables don't update in real time.

Is it possible to get the variables to update in real time?

http://jsfiddle.net/9w7cdn80/2/

```
$(function() {
     $("#pin").draggable();
});
$( document ).ready(function() {
     var yPos = $("#pin").css('top');
     var xPos = $("#pin").css('left');
     $('#wcd-y').val(yPos);
     $('#wcd-x').val(xPos);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind to the `drag` event.

```
$("#pin").draggable({
  drag: function() {
    // Update
  }
});
```

Comment: Any idea why the values of the input aren't loading by default? I'm trying to get it so that whatever the current Top and Left properties are loaded when the page is launched, so that the inputs are never blank.